# CFSharepoint integration of ColdFusion with SharePoint

Tags: coldfusion, cfml, coldfusion-2016

I'm trying to integrate ColdFusion version 2016 application with SharePoint. I have a ColdFusion app that is trying to access a csv file on a SharePoint site. I'm able to access the csv file on SharePoint when I pass in the URL into a browser, but unable to access it from CF. I tried several different combinations of the  tag but keep getting one of the following errors:

```
1) '401 UNAUTHORIZED'
2) Error: org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connect to 
   DomainName:80
```

(Note: In the second error, I masked the actual domain name for security purposes).

I confirmed with the SharePoint admin that the domain name, username and password are set up correctly and he did confirm the same. Has anyone tried this type of integration and run into the same issues, and how was it solved?

Code for a couple of the combinations of cfsharepoint that I tried is below:

Using cfscript:

```
<cfscript>

    loginStruct = {domain="xxxxx", username="abc123", password="xyz$566",authtype="ntlm", wsdl="https://mywebsite.com/sites/xxx-Home/_vti_bin/Lists.asmx?wsdl"};

    cfsharepoint(action="getlistcollection", login=loginStruct, name="myResult");

    writeDump(myResult);
    //writeDump(loginStruct);
</cfscript>
```

Using :

```
<cfsharepoint action="getlistcollection"  
        WSDL="https://mywebsite.com/sites/xxx-Home/LED_Docs/Forms/AllItems.aspx?WSDL"
        username="abc123"
        domain="xxxx"
        password="xyz$566"
        name="listCollection"/>
        authtype="NTLM"
        <CFDUMP var="#listCollection#">
```

Comment: Can you browse to your WSDL link?

Comment: And is the certificate for the HTTPS stored in your Java keystore?

Comment: @Shawn - yes, I can browse to the link and view the file. I don't know if there is a cert in the java keystore since the CF server is hosted and I don't have access to it.

Comment: Is the `/>` a typo in your `Using:` example? You're closing the tag before specifying NTLM authentication. Move the tag closing to after your `authtype` argument.

Comment: Ah.... note from Adobe: https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/using/ntlm-support.html `When the login attribute is used, then the NTLM attributes must go into the login struct. For example, loginStruct = {domain="myDomain", username="user name", password="pa$$w0rd", authtype="ntlm", ntlmdomain="myNTLMDomain"};`. Does that change work?  Also, https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/cfml-reference/coldfusion-tags/tags-r-s/cfsharepoint.html

Comment: @Shawn - yes I believe I've tried that - if you look at my OP, the first method I tried using cfscript has ntlm in it; I did have ntlmdomain as well but removed it at some point - can ntlmdomain have any arbitrary name? Where is the ntlmdomain name found?

Comment: You have `domain`, but for NTLM Auth, you also need to include an `ntlmdomain` attribute.

Comment: It would be the name of the directory your users are authenticating against. Are you using Active Directory?

Comment: Shawn - yes, the SharePoint admin notified that they're using AD for authentication - and all the credentials are fine; how would I get the ntlm domain name? Would that be something that the Sharepoint admin would know?

Comment: Probably. But I believe it should be the AD group that the user you're using in the `cfsharepoint` tag. I'm not 100% sure of the difference between the two, but I'll look into it.

Comment: I given up on cfsharepoint and instead trying a jquery ajax solution. I posted a question about that which is here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52645847/performing-ntlm-authentication-in-jquery-ajax-get-call

Comment: Is this Sharepoint server on your internal network? Can you reach the server resources without using HTTPS?

Comment: Yes, it's on our internal network, no I can't access it without https.